# Ignore sudo for each command

Tags: bash, sudo

I am currently working on a Linux variation in which default user is root and there is no possibility to use sudo commands, because there is no such package installed and there is no option to add it in this case. All commands are executed with root privileges by default. Using sudo prints `sh: sudo: not found` error.

Unfortunately, I have a test repository which has a lot of commands with `sudo`, because these tests are executed on other distributions of Linux as well.

My question is: can I prepare some bash script, or something like that, which would skip `sudo` in any command?

What I mean is that when I execute sudo command like
`sudo cat <some_path>`, I would like it to execute as `cat <some_path>`, dropping the `sudo` part. It could work that way for every command, so the script could be e.g. run at startup and work for every sudo command.

Comment: Note that `sudo` can be used by root to assume another user's identity for some command, so just making the `sudo` command a no-op would potentially not do what you want. It would probably be easy to replace `sudo` with a small script that wraps around `su`, or, if you trust that `sudo` is only ever used for gaining root privileges, removes any `sudo` options and just executes the given command.

Comment: In this case I don't need assuming another user's identity because on this setup there is no other user and will not be on this one. But anyway, thanks for this insight.

Comment: `echo "sh -c \$*" >/usr/bin/sudo && chmod 755 /usr/bin/sudo`. The concept of having an administrator account be separate from user accounts is there for a reason though. root priviliges should be used sparingly, and [not at all for GUI programs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Running_GUI_applications_as_root).

Comment: @Hexagonical I'm not talking about your system. I'm talking about the script you're running and the assumptions it could possibly be making.

Comment: @Vilinkameni Note that you most likely want that script to use `sh "$@"`, or just `eval "$@"`, but it does not take care of the case where `sudo` may be used with options.

Comment: Right, I haven't tested the code thoroughly. It's such an unusual request anyway, and the entire idea should be rethinked.

Comment: Here's a working version (minus the sudo options): `echo "\"\$@\"" > /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 755 /usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: The script was one way I was thinking of but alias as mentioned in answer below will work too. This is quite specific problem and I need it only for testing purposes, but of course wouldn't recommend this kind of "workaround" on a target platform for user.

Comment: How would you want to handle `sudo -b some_command`, where the `-b` flag tells `sudo` to run it in the background (much like `some_command &`? Also, might any of the scripts using `sudo` expect to have the environment reset? I'm not sure it's as simple as just making `sudo` a no-op

Comment: @roaima One could add option parsing using getopts(1) or getopt(1) if desired. But as I stated above, the overall aim of having a root-only system is questionable. It would be comparable to MS DOS in terms of security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set an alias like this: `alias sudo=""`

Comment: Aliases are not expanded in scripts by default (and are also not inherited from the calling environment). Also, what would happen with e.g. `sudo -u otheruser some-command` or any other `sudo` command with options to `sudo`?

Comment: Good point, so one would have to use `shopt -s expand_aliases`
inside the script.

Comment: @Harry what if it isn't a shell script that runs sudo? It isn't a good solution.

Comment: Fortunately, in this case there is completely no need to use any kind of changing privileges nor permissions. Only platform-specific commands which there are a lot right now. I did not see any sense in adding "try/except" in every single test command for sudo and non-sudo variations.

Answer (score 2):

A simple no-op passthrough script would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
"$@"
```

It just takes the arguments it's given, and runs a command using them, using the first one as the command name. So if installed as `sudo` somewhere in `$PATH`, running `sudo ls -l "what ever"`, should do the same as just `ls -l "what ever"`.

Of course, it won't look at any options, and e.g. `sudo -s` would try to run a command called `-s`, probably giving an error.